# RegEx for .txt containing all cities in the world using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a .txt file containing:

**Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude,Longitude**

.. for all cities in the world (3.000.000+ cities). Link to file [here](http://download.maxmind.com/download/worldcities/worldcitiespop.txt.gz).

I want to use the RegEx replace functionality in Notepad++ to change the list, so that the output will be as follows:

**AccentCity,Country**

The "Country" data should be capitalized. **Here is an exmaple:**

[Example before and after RegEx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mln9P.jpg)

```
ad,aixas,Aixàs,06,,42.4833333,1.4666667
ad,aixirivali,Aixirivali,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirivall,Aixirivall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirvall,Aixirvall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixovall,Aixovall,06,,42.4666667,1.4833333
dk,ebeltoft,Ebeltoft,18,5888,56.201801,10.682258
.......

Aixàs,AD
Aixirivali,AD
Aixirivall,AD
Aixirvall,AD
Aixovall,AD
Ebeltoft,DK
```

I am new to RegEx and i can't seem to be getting it right. I hope someone can help me.

Best regards, Anton

Comment: Please paste the sample data from your picture as actual (code formatted) text. How far did you get in your own attempts?

Comment: Sorry. It is done now. My attempts messed it all up.

Comment: For future readers: This specific example could be found/replaced using `^(.*?),.*?,(.*?),.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?$` as the find pattern, and `$1, $2` as the replacement (and use the editor afterwards to fix case.

Comment: @Hiphop03199: Have you seen Deltharis 's answer?

Comment: There is a much easier approach using Excel: import as a comma-delimited CSV, then remove unnecessary columns, swap the remaining ones, apply uppercase on the necessary column and concatenate the two column values.

Comment: You won't be able to use Excel with a file of that size. I tried it and it didn't work. Deltharis's answer did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find:

```
^([^,]+),[^,]+,([^,]+).*
```

Replace with:

```
$2,\U$1
```

Find is as straightforward as it could be - line start, find non-comma characters in group 1, comma, non-comma chars, comma, non-comma characters in group 2, rest of the line. Assumes all the comma separated groups up to AccentCity are always filled with at least one character.

replace changing the order, and adding \U to capitalize group 1.

Comment: Oh! Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: @Toto for finding itself it's useless, but it's there so that replace removes all the unnecessary data. If it was missing output would not look as specified (it would have remaining fields afterwards)